# AWS AppFlow - multiple destinations on a single flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-appflow

We are looking at exploring AppFlow for ingesting data from a 3rd party SaaS.
AppFlow has out of the box connectors for that 3rd party SaaS.

One of the destinations for the data coming in will be AWS Snowflake.
The same data also needs to be sent over to a custom API endpoint, using some custom code developed using AppFlow paython/ java SDK.

Question I have is - can the same flow be connected to multiple destinations - both snowflake and custom API endpoint?
OR would we have to configure 2 flows - both connecting to the same source, but destination for one will be snowflake and for the other flow it will be custom API endpoint.

Thanks,